# Can node modules require each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm having the following 3 files.

user.js requires room.js and room.js requires user.js.

user.js

```
var Room = require('./room.js');

var User = function () {};
User.prototype.test = function () {
  return new Room();
};

module.exports = User;
```

room.js

```
var User = require('./user.js');

var Room = function () {};
Room.prototype.test = function () {
  return new User();
};

module.exports = Room;
```

index.js

```
var User = require('./user.js');
var Room = require('./room.js');

var user = new User();
var room = new Room();

user.test();
room.test();
```

index.js requires both room and user.

Here's the problem. When I run index.js, I will get a TypeError from 'new User()' in room.js. It seems that User in room.js is hidden by the User in index.js.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this kind of requiring allowed? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check out http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles for how this is handled in node.

You can solve your problem in several ways, for example passing in the dependencies to the instances aka *Dependency Injection*

```
// user.js
var User = function (Room) { this.Room = Room; };
User.prototype.test = function () {
  return new this.Room();
};
module.exports = User;

// room.js
var Room = function (User) { this.User = User; };
Room.prototype.test = function () {
  return new this.User();
};
module.exports = Room;

// index.js
var User = require('./user.js');
var Room = require('./room.js');

var user = new User(Room);
var room = new Room(User);
```

Another way would be to require the files only when you need them

```
// user.js
var User = function () {};
User.prototype.test = function () {
  var Room = require('./room');
  return new Room();
};
module.exports = User;


// room.js
var Room = function () {};
Room.prototype.test = function () {
  var User = require('./user');
  return new User();
};
module.exports = Room;

// index.js
var User = require('./user.js');
var Room = require('./room.js');

var user = new User();
var room = new Room();
```

Like this, your exports are defined by the time you need them.

But generally, if you have circular dependencies, you are doing something wrong and should think about your architecture. 
If a `User` needs to create new `Rooms` and a `Room` needs to create new `Users`, it seems like they both have too much responsibility.
Possibly you would want a third component which is responsible for creating and passing the right instances to the `Room` and `User`, instead of having them instantiate those directly.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Re-architecturing seems the best way to go :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the second option. Since, importing a module is a synchronous task. It could block the main thread.

Answer (score 16):

I think there is much better way how to do it. Just switch export and require like this:

user.js

```
var User = function () {};
module.exports = User;    

User.prototype.test = function () {
    return new Room();
};

var Room = require('./room.js');
```

room.js

```
var Room = function () {};
module.exports = Room;    

Room.prototype.test = function () {
  return new User();
};

var User = require('./user.js');
```

index.js

```
var User = require('./user.js');
var Room = require('./room.js');

var user = new User();
var room = new Room();

user.test();
room.test();
```

check this article: https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js

Comment: Wow! since the creating of www, this is the most genius thing i ever see, this should be the correct answer, thank you

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but I had refactored code to go from the constructor method to this method and I had to throw a seemingly gratuitous `bind()` into some code that used to work.  I didn't take the time to get a root cause, but beware.. (`this` was undefined is the only definitive symptom when passing a member function as an argument). I do like this method but that was another wasted hour...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between:

```
/* code above */
function a() {};
```

and

```
/* code above */
var a = function () {};
```

Is that in the first example `a` will be **function** already in the `code above`, but not in the second example.

Once you understand that you can come to this simple solution:

// user.js

```
module.exports = User;

function User() {};
User.prototype.test = function () {
  var Room = require('./room');
  return new Room();
};
```

// room.js

```
module.exports = Room;

function Room() {};
Room.prototype.test = function () {
  var User = require('./user');
  return new User();
};
```

// index.js

```
var User = require('./user.js');
var Room = require('./room.js');

var user = new User(Room);
var room = new Room(User);
```