# GraphQL: One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, node-modules

I'm learning GraphQL so I got a strange issue

I have this code on one file Schema.js:

```
const graphQL = require('graphql');
const lodash = require('lodash')
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLList } = graphQL;

const StatusType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Status',
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLInt },
    statusName: { type: GraphQLString },
    user: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            
        }
    }
})
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'User',
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    mail: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { 
        type: StatusType,
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            
        }
    },
})
});

const RouteQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'RouteQuery',
user: {
        type: UserType,
        args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            //return lodash.find(users, { id: args.id })
        }
    },
userSome: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            if (args.id) {
                //return users.filter(user => user.id === args.id);
            }
            //return users;
        }
    },
userAll: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        resolve(parentValue){
            //return users
        }
    },
status:{
        type: StatusType,
        args: { id: { type: GraphQLInt } },
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            //return lodash.find(status, { id: args.id })
        }
    },
statusAll: {
        type: new GraphQLList(StatusType),
        resolve(parentValue){
            //return users
        }
    }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
query: RouteQuery
})
```

This code run succesfully but when i try to separate these into multiple files:  the `const StatusType & UserType` like the following case:
the StatusType is on StatusType.js file and the UserType is on UserType.js file

StatuType.js file:

```
const graphQL = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLList } = graphQL;
const UserType = require('./UserType')
const StatusType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Status',
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLInt },
    statusName: { type: GraphQLString },
    user: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            //return users.filter(user => user.status === parentValue.id);
        }
    }
})
});
module.exports = StatusType;
```

UserType.js file:

```
const graphQL = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLList } = graphQL;
const StatusType = require('./StatusType')

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'User',
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    mail: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { 
        type: StatusType,
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            //return lodash.find(status, { id: parentValue.status })
        }
    },
})
});
module.exports = UserType;
```

And on the Schema.js file i include these 2 like that:

```
const StatusType = require('./StatusType');
const UserType = require('./UserType');
```

so instead of putting the all code on the same file, i putted the StatusType and UserType on respective files.

but when i run this code, i got this error:

[image]

So i don't know what the problem here :/

But when i'm tring to console.log the `const UserType = require('./UserType')` i got `User` as response :o like when it was on the same code on Schema.js

Answer (score 7):

You are facing a problem in the way nodeJs handle `require`. See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles for how `require` is handled in node.

Specifically in your case, when you do:

```js
const StatusType = require('./StatusType');
const UserType = require('./UserType');
```

1. `StatusType` is loaded from `const StatusType = require('./StatusType');`
2. *StatusType.js* loads `UserType` from `const UserType = require('./UserType')`
3. *UserType.js* should require `StatusType` but nodeJs prevent this to avoid infinite loop. As a result, it executes next lines
4. `UserType` is initialized as `new GraphQLObjectType(...)` and defined `fields` as a function. The function closure hand a variable `StatusType` not yet initialized. It's just an empty exported module `{}`

You can verify that adding `console.log(StatusType);` when creating `UserType` fields:

```js
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => {
    console.log(StatusType);
    return ({
      id: { type: GraphQLString },
      username: { type: GraphQLString },
      mail: { type: GraphQLString },
      password: { type: GraphQLString },
      status: {
        type: StatusType,
        resolve(parentValue, args) {

        }
      },
    });
  }
});
```

You'll get:

```sh
{} //instead of StatusType
```

You didn't encounter this problem when everything was in the same file because both `UserType` and `StatusType` are defined within the same closure and now each others.

To resolve that you had to define `UserType` and `StatusType` on the same level and inject them. A good example of how to do it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341883/can-node-modules-require-each-other). In your case:

```js
// StatusType.js
const StatusType = (types) => new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Status',
  fields: () => {
    console.log(types.UserType);
    return ({
      id: { type: GraphQLInt },
      statusName: { type: GraphQLString },
      user: {
        type: new GraphQLList(types.UserType),
        resolve(parentValue, args) {

        }
      }
    });
  }
});

module.exports = StatusType;

// UserType.js
const UserType = (types) => new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => {
    console.log(types.StatusType);
    return ({
      id: { type: GraphQLString },
      username: { type: GraphQLString },
      mail: { type: GraphQLString },
      password: { type: GraphQLString },
      status: {
        type: types.StatusType,
        resolve(parentValue, args) {

        }
      },
    });
  }
});
module.exports = UserType;

// Schema.js
const StatusTypeInject = require('./StatusType');
const UserTypeInject = require('./UserType');

const types = {};
types.StatusType = StatusTypeInject(types);
types.UserType = UserTypeInject(types);

const StatusType = types.StatusType;
const UserType = types.UserType;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do with some cleaning up here and here's how I'd resolve these situations:

```js
[..]
// import GraphQLNonNull from the graphql lib
// In your case, I'd use GraphQLID instead of GraphQLString

userSome: {
  type: new GraphQLList(require('../path/to/UserType')),
  args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
  resolve: async (parentValue, args) => {
    // No need for the if statement as we'd sure to have an id.
    // return await filter users by id.
  }
},
[..]
```

And as always, keep your `fields` as functions: `fields: () => ({})`

Answer (score 0):

Injection solves this error

```js
// StatusType.js
 
const StatusType = (types) => new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Status',
  fields: () => {
    console.log(types.UserType);
    return ({
      id: { type: GraphQLInt },
      statusName: { type: GraphQLString },
      user: {
        type: new GraphQLList(types.UserType),
        resolve(parentValue, args) {

        }
      }
    });
  }
});

module.exports = StatusType;
```

Create a types.js file in your directory.
Here you can add all your types that integrate with other types and inject the required types.

```js
const UserTypeInject = require("./UserType");
const StatusTypeInject = require("./Author");

const types = {};
types.UserType = UserTypeInject(types);
types.StatusType = StatusTypeInject(types);

const UserType = types.UserType;
const StatusType = types.StatusType;

module.exports = { UserType, StatusType };
```

Whenever you need the type either in Mutations or Queries, you import it from the types.js files as such;

```js
const { UserType } = require("../types");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORvCG.png

Please see the above Image and code line: 5.
I was inserting data into my **client** collection using **Mutation** GraphQL and used a single quote for ClientType ('ClientType') and got the same error. I have just removed a single quote as the type wants the client GraphQLObjectType and I was providing ClientType as String.

I searched for it for 2 days.
Hope it will help anyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You are importing UserType inside StatusType before declaration.

```
const StatusType = require('./StatusType');
const UserType = require('./UserType');
```